# How ignore conflicts in Yast (Opensuse Leap 42.2)

Tags: package-management, opensuse, yast

For some reasons, I had to flag some packets as taboo to prevent installation and unexpected configuration changes.

For example, I've blocked nouveau drivers, because I use Nvidia proprietary drivers, and OpenJDK because I use Oracle JDK.

My issue, is when I try to update some packages like Libreoffice, I get tons of conflicts errors because LibreOffice has a dependency with OpenJDK.

So everytime I need to flag manually all packages to ignore the conflict.

There is a way to tell at Yast to remember what conflicts should ignore one time for all?

[image: Yast Conflicts]

Answer (score 0):

You can easily have multiple installs of java, and choose the one to use : With the /etc/alternatives/ mechanism :

```
# /usr/sbin/update-alternatives --config java
```

And : Libreoffice has no problem using the Oracle java.

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't sole my Issue, and doesn't answer my question: 1) I know LibreOffice has no problem using Oracle JDK, this is the reason I want use Oracle JDK only.

Comment: 2) I already tried to use the alternatives config mechanism, but everytime I update the openJDK, it breaks the configuration. 3) this doesn't help me with other packages, like some libraries that depends from nouveau

Comment: 4) Why I should install those fake dependencies?, on my system these are dangerous, and I've already replaced them with correct working libraries. I simply need to ignore these fake conflicts. And I think it's very stupid if I can ignore them only manually. 5) In my question I asked how to ignore conflicts one time for all, not how to solve  LibreOffice conflicts.